# Laravel: One to Many Poly relation not updating automatically

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm, relationship

3 types of posts: Personal, Business & Nature.

Below is the Post Model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

Relation::morphMap([
          'Personal' => 'App\Personal',
          'Business' => 'App\Business',
          'Nature' => 'App\Nature',
        ]);

class Post extends Model
{
    public function postable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }        
}
```

Below is the Personal Model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;    

class Personal extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Post::class,'postable');
    }
}
```

Likewise Busines & Nature models.

When I manually enter the data in phpMyAdmin, the tinker shows the result as required, but when I create a post from front-end (via form), the `posts` table remains unchanged.

I tried googling, but nothing works! :(

Below is the PersonalController

```php
public function create()
    {
        if(Auth::guest()){
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
        $sectors = Sector::all();
        $cities = City::all();
        $ranges = Range::all();
        return view('front.personal-register',compact('sectors','cities','ranges'));
    }

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            "sectors" => "required",
            "cities" => "required",
            "ranges" => "required",
            "g-recaptcha-response" => "required|captcha"
        ]);

    $franchisee = new Personal;
    $franchisee->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $franchisee->save();

    $franchisee->sectors()->sync($request->sectors);
    $franchisee->cities()->sync($request->cities);
    $franchisee->ranges()->sync($request->ranges);

    return redirect(route('personal.index'))->with('message','Thank You! Your post has been added');
}
```

Comment: Please post your controller code.

Comment: Which controller? @Jonas

Comment: The controller where you process the form data.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I have added the controller, pls hav a look.

Comment: I don't see any code that updates the `posts` table.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir As mentioned in the start of the question, their are 3 types of  posts (Personal, Business & Nature), & I have updated the PersonalController code, please check

Comment: Try with `$franchisee = new Personal($request->get());` that should solve the issue.